# I want the P tag text on the same line next to each other

Tags: css, responsive-design, alignment

I've been trying to align the P tag text left and right next to each other but can't get it to do so. They are both within the same divs and I'm coding in ems and % could anyone help?

Comment: code please, show us your code.

Comment: you want to destroy the sense of the p-tag... use the span-tag instead

Answer (score 6):

You should use span instead of p which has a default display of inline

```
<span>Your text here</span>
```

The p element is default display block. If you insist on using p, then you need to dive into some CSS. Set a class for the p element (or ID if it is unique) like so

```
<p class="inline-p">Your text here </p>
```

Then in a separate CSS file, use a selector to reference that class. Please try to avoid inline CSS in your HTML. It can become a nightmare to maintain later.

```
.inline-p {
     // Modify display for this class
     display: inline;
}
```

You should avoid modifying the properties of HTML tags when there is an existing HTML tag that can accomplish what you are looking to do. Nevertheless, both your options are presented here. Good luck with your website.

Comment: Displaying <p> side by side is un-natural as Paul said because you have to do it by 'BRUTAL FORCE' but if you use <span> instead it will do naturally, no .css needed. E.g: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/wdQJd/

Answer (score 5):

make display:inline; for p tag

Answer (score 1):

You can't align text left and right in the same p tag unless you use span.   But you could do it using the CSS float property

```
<p style="float: left">Some text on the left</p>
<p style="float: right">Some text on the right</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted any code for us to analyze, so speaking generally... you can mess with the "display" CSS style and floats to get them lined up as you need, or you could use a more appropriate tag that is already inline, like a span.